# Correct way to add both time-varying and time-invariant predictors in coxph()

Tags: r, survival, modeling, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

I have time-varying and time-invariant predictors in my cox model. What will be the correct way to add both of them using `coxph()`? In my model, income, development, and gender are time invariant and gazeaway, gazepicture, and posture are time varying.

I know to add solely time-varying predictors, we need to create intervals which have a `start` and `stop` time to be fed in the `Surv()` function:

```
model <- coxph(Surv(start, stop, Listener.state) ~ income + development + gender + gazeaway +  gazepicture + posture, data=compsviv121)
suumary(model)
                         coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z        p
income              0.0399364  1.0407446  0.0136684  2.922  0.00348
development        -0.0006316  0.9993686  0.0005616 -1.125  0.26073
gender              0.0604521  1.0623167  0.0259312  2.331  0.01974
gazeaway            0.3122407  1.3664836  0.0608410  5.132 2.87e-07
gazepicture         0.2722540  1.3129205  0.0453264  6.007 1.90e-09
posture            -0.1379867  0.8711103  0.0861360 -1.602  0.10916
```

But is this correct even if I have time-invariant predictors `income`, `development`, and `gender`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this type of analysis, each row of the data must show *all* covariate values that hold for an individual during the corresponding `(start, stop]` time interval. If a covariate is constant in time, its value needs to be copied into each row for that individual.

See the end of Section 2 of the [time dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) for the R survival package. There's an example with time-varying creatinine values and a time-constant covariate of age at study entry:

> In this case the variable age = age at entry to the study stays the same from line to line, while the value of creatinine varies...

Comment: Thank you @EdM. This is very helpful!